# Javascript syntax error when trying to use a variable in the argument of a function

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

I have a slider (the slick.js one) and I want to filter my slide by colors (red,green,blue).
In my chrome console, it works fine when I filter using this syntax:

```js
$('.my-class').slick('slickFilter', '.green');
```

However, now I want to change `'.green'` automatically. For this, in my file I have a variable called `selected_color` which return: red, green or blue.

However, in my file, if I do this:

```js
var selected_color = variant.featured_image.alt;
// the next line is for debug purpose        
console.log(selected_color, "'." + selected_color + "'");      
$('.my-class').slick('slickFilter', "'." + selected_color + "'");
```

It returns me:

```
green '.green'
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.green'
```

I don't get where I made a syntax error because the `"'." + selected_color + "'"` returned `'.green'` and that's working in the console.

Comment: Why have you put extra quotes *inside* the string?

Comment: You're wrapping it in apostrophes when you shouldn't

Comment: Just `$('.my-class').slick('slickFilter', "." + selected_color);`

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to JS. What do you mean by extra quotes / apostrophes ?

Comment: Consider using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of [string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition).

Comment: `var x = 'y'` <= the single quotes there are not literal quotes.  They are delimiters that javascript will use to determine where the string value starts and stops.  The resulting string, itself, will not contain single quotes.  When you do `"'."` you are putting literal single quotes in the string

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. Indeed deleting the extra quotes make it work. However I don't get it. Why in the console I need the extra quotes but not anymore in my function. I feel stupid even if this is my first time coding a Js function but I need to know. EDIT: Thanks @Taplar. Just read your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, I had extra quotes when I shoudn't. What I needed to do was: `$('.my-class').slick('slickFilter', "." + selected_color);`.